# How to reply to a reviewer in Apple App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

my boss wants me to figure out a way to get the contact information of people who leave helpful reviews in the Apple app store. He wishes to personally email these reviewers to give them feedback/progress information. After about an hour of googling I couldn't find any information although it seems that google app store allows you to do this. Can someone confirm that this is not possible?

Comment: We're starting a proposal for questions about App Stores: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores?referrer=Znmz97Ak7ERjuiuCuAdO9A2 If it started, you might be better accepted there.

Comment: The proposal has been closed, this is a real problem in the App Store and developer should finally be able to answer on the reviews of their customer

Comment: That's now possible right from iTunes Connect. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277926/201567

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't respond to app reviews. Check out this article written 6/22/12: http://thenextweb.com/apple/2012/06/22/its-time-for-apple-to-allow-developers-to-respond-to-app-store-reviews/

Comment: According to the latest news since public iOS 10.3 release we will be able to respond app views. Check out this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10_3.html

Comment: That's now possible right from iTunes Connect. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277926/201567